# Can't figure out what monad function I'm looking for

Tags: haskell, monads

I thought it was `liftM` but the type signature doesn't seem right. I was hoping for a function like:

```
 someFunc :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> a -> m b
 someFunc f = return . f
```

I know I can define this with the above code, but my gut says this has to already exist and I'm just not seeing it for whatever reason.

eg:

```
main = do
    n_tmp <- getLine
    let n = read n_tmp :: Int
```

vs

```
main = do
    getLine >>= someFunc read :: IO Int
```

Or am I just doing things horribly wrong?

Comment: In this particular case, probably just use `readLn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Half-jokingly, you are looking for `(return.)`, a simple partial application of `(.)` to the `return` function. It's hardly more typing that would be required for any reasonable name that might be assigned to it:

```
someFunc :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> a -> m b
someFunc = (return.)
-- or someFunc = (.)return
```

Compare

```
getLine >>= someFunc read :: IO Int
getLine >>= return.read :: IO Int
```

Answer (score 9):

In cases like this I just use fmap....

```
main = do
    n <- fmap read getLine
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just got stuck on the idea of having to use `>>=` for some reason